# Windows equivalent of the linux whatis command

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash

New super user here. Does windows have an equivalent of the Linux `whatis` command? I'm also new to the Linux terminal but I have found the `whatis` really helpful with commands I have forgotten their specific use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"whatis" is a form of help command.

The closest thing to a "whatis" style of command is "help" in Windows (which I use).

So help ver yields "Display Windows Version"

held dir yields:

> C:>help dir Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a
> directory.
>
> DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]   [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]
>
> [drive:][path][filename]
> Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.
>
> /A          Displays files with specified attributes.   attributes
> D  Directories                R  Read-only files
> H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
> S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
> L  Reparse Points             O  Offline files
> -  Prefix meaning not   /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).   /C          Display the
> thousand separator in file sizes.  This is the
> default.  Use /-C to disable display of separator.   /D          Same as wide but files are list sorted by column.   /L          Uses
> lowercase.   /N          New long list format where filenames are on
> the far right.   /O          List by files in sorted order.
> sortorder    N  By name (alphabetic)       S  By size (smallest first)
> E  By extension (alphabetic)  D  By date/time (oldest first)
> G  Group directories first    -  Prefix to reverse order   /P          Pauses after each screenful of information.   /Q
> Display the owner of the file.   /R          Display alternate data
> streams of the file.   /S          Displays files in specified
> directory and all subdirectories.

Get-Help is a Powershell help command that is like HELP in Windows cmd shell but much more expansive because Powershell is a programming language.

Comment: help works for what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Thought to upvote it but I do not have enough reputation yet.

Comment: You can upvote in a few minutes. (waiting period).

Comment: Apparently, I can upvote. The change is not just recorded because I don't have enough reputation yet.